# How to debug "[proxy] Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND" from Gulp?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, gulp

I am unable to resolve this with `gulp serve`:

> [proxy] Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: do those hosts exist?

Comment: ya. I am getting this when I run gulp serve. localhost is running but getting this error at the end

Comment: This is a very open question but there are good ways to tackle it. I have described them in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The error `ENOTFOUND getaddrinfo` looks like it cannot reach a host somewhere. **gulp** is completely asynchronous so the error messages is not necessarily in any order.

Since your request is to have **help resolving the issue** I would recommend the following:

### identify problem gulp task

Look for the error in incomplete gulp tasks

You can see which tasks have started and finished in the log by examining the messages. e.g.

```
starting "styles"
finished "styles" after 780ms
```

`styles` above is an example of a completed gulp task.

Based on this pattern you can see all listed tasks are **complete**:

```
styles, scripts, inject, watch, server, scripts:watch
```

However, if you look at the first `gulp-inject` message you can see that it comes before `starting "inject"`. So the last messages may be part of a task that has started but has not yet printed it's status.

### Locate and debug problem gulp task

The tasks are defined in your **gulpfile.js** (or *require*d therein)

Inside your gulp file a task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('somename', <function()> or [list of tasks])
```

You should look for

```
gulp.task('serve', ['watch', 'scripts', etc..])
```

Have a look for any tasks listed there which you do not see in the gulp output above. It may be one of those that has started that you need to debug to get closer to your answer.

HTH.

Comment: scripts:watch is also finished after 95ms. see below.

Comment: @Ved: Hmm that is true. Still, the approach is generally valid. Can you look and see where the message "Webpack is watching for changes". comes from? Is it inside some task? Could be a tasks that has started but hasn't printed that it has yet (like inject above)